# Add space above a footer using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have CSS code with HTML, and I would like to add space above the footer since my tables stick to the footer directly.

Please make sure every time I add a table, space should be there between tables and the footer.

You can view my code at http://jsfiddle.net/hadinetcat/E8jd3/6/

#### CSS code

```
<style type='text/css'>

    .container3 {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        /* background:green; */
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }

    .container2 {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        background: #FFA500;
        position: relative;
        right: 45%;
    }

    .container1 {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        /* background:red; */
        position: relative;
        right: 40%;
    }

    .col1 {
        float: left;
        width: 26%;
        position: relative;
        left: 87%;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 570px;
    }

    .col2 {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        position: relative;
        left: 90%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .col3 {
        float: left;
        width: 26%;
        position: relative;
        left: 80%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .footer {
        border: 1px solid orange;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0px;
        margin-top: -5px;
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    .signout {
        position: absolute;
        width: 200;
        bottom: 150px;
        left: 5px;
        clear: both;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center
    }
</style>
```

#### HTML

```
<div id="header" style="background-color:#FFA500;">

<h1 style="margin-bottom:0;">Wellcome To Balhalfe Services Customer Reports</h1>

<div class="container3 ">
    <div class="container1 ">
        <div class="container2 ">

        <div class="col1">
            lalalallalalalallala <br />
            lllllllllllllllllllll <br />
        </div>

        <div class="col2">
            <div align="center">
                <H2 align="center"> Report Table</H></div>

                <table border="1" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Name</b></td>
                        <td><b>Mime</b></td>
                        <td><b>Size (bytes)</b></td>
                        <td><b>Created</b></td>
                        <td><b>Download</b></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                        <td>application/pdf</td>
                        <td>60964</td>
                        <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                        <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>eu contres.txt</td>
                        <td>text/plain</td>
                        <td>546</td>
                        <td>2013-08-22 00:06:55</td>
                        <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=4&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                        <td>application/pdf</td>
                        <td>60964</td>
                        <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                        <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                        <td>application/pdf</td>
                        <td>60964</td>
                        <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                        <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                        <td>application/pdf</td>
                        <td>60964</td>
                        <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                        <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                        <td>application/pdf</td>
                        <td>60964</td>
                        <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                        <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                        <td>application/pdf</td>
                        <td>60964</td>
                        <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                        <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                        <td>application/pdf</td>
                        <td>60964</td>
                        <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                        <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                        <td>application/pdf</td>
                        <td>60964</td>
                        <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                        <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                        <td>application/pdf</td>
                        <td>60964</td>
                        <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                        <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                        <td>application/pdf</td>
                        <td>60964</td>
                        <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                        <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                        <td>application/pdf</td>
                        <td>60964</td>
                        <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                        <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div>

            <div class="col3">
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="signout">

    <a  style='text-decoration:none;' href= "index.html">Sign Out </br></a>

</div>

<div class="footer" style="background-color:#FFA500;clear:both;text-align:center;">
    Copyright © balhalfe services 20103-2014</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Give your footer a positive `margin-top`.

Comment: Based on your JsFiddle, I would just add some `padding-top` to your `.footer`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/E8jd3/11/

Comment: View my posted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213014/css-add-space-above-footer/19213087#19213087

Comment: @hadi updated answer check it out http://jsfiddle.net/sunilkumar707/H8ns3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E8jd3/11/).

Add some pixels to table `margin-bottom` in CSS.

For example,

```css
table{
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't touch anything. Just add `padding-bottom: 20px;` in `.col2`.

`.col2` is the container for you body table.

Try this:

```css
.col2 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    left: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

[New Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sunilkumar707/H8ns3/)

Comment: Please demonstrate with a JSfiddle as this does not seem to work based on the OP's example.

Comment: your code is working fine - just add this  `margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;`

Comment: @Paulie_D, when i add your code it seams left side bar getting split from the footer..col1

Answer (score 2):

Give a bigger margin to your footer like this:

```css
footer {
    border: 1px solid orange;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Comment: I just edited the answer: `.footer` --> `footer`, to include the standard `<footer>` tag, assuming that was the intent of the author.